# Needs clarification on C# Flags

Tags: c#, flags

i have this code:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyUriType {
    ForParse,
    ForDownload,
    Unknown
}
```

and then:

```
MyUriType uriType = MyUriType.ForDownload;
```

but, I was wondering why this returns true:

```
if ((uriType & MyUriType.ForParse) == MyUriType.ForParse)
```

When it is not set in the second code group. Please advise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the first field for an `enum` type is given the ordinal value `0`.

So, if `uriType` does not contain the `MyUriType.ForParse` flag, then `uriType & MyUriType.ForParse` actually equals `0`, which counterintuitively evaluates to `true` when you compare it to `MyUriType.ForParse` for equality (which is also `0`).

If you break it down to bitwise arithmetic then the expression you're evaluating is:

```
({something} & 0) == 0
```

...which will always evaluate to `true`, no matter what the "something" is.

Normally, when you define a `Flags` enum, you should actually specify values for each field:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyUriTypes
{
    None = 0,
    ForParse = 1,
    ForDownload = 2,
    ForSomethingElse = 4,
    ForAnotherThing = 8
}
```

Each value should be a power of 2 so that they don't conflict (every multiple of 2 is a binary shift-left).

It's also customary to name it as a plural, so that people who use the enum know that it is a `Flags` enum and can/should hold multiple values.

If you define your enum this way, your test code will now evaluate to `false` if `uriType` does not have the `ForParse` bit set.

Comment: For enums with a lot of fields, you can use hex literals to simplify value assignment: ... ForAnotherThing = 0x8, ForThatOneOtherThing = 0x10, OhYeahAndThatThing = 0x20, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should define it in powers of 2 like:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyUriType {
None = 0
ForParse = 1,
ForDownload = 2,
Unknown = 4
}
```

Note that flags are appropriate when you expect a combination of options to be set (e.g. ForParse + Unknown or ForDownload + Unknown).  If only one option at a time applies, you can use a regular enum.